# JEE6 war packing into several modules

Tags: jpa, jar, ejb, war, packaging

I want to split parts of my WAR application into different JAR components.
Every JAR component contains JPA-Entities, EJBs & JSF-Composite-Components.

Example: extracting the user management (XHTMLs, EJBs, JPA-Entities) into an own jar.

At first everything looks working fine as long as I don't have to use an entityManager.

Problem:
In EJBs of JAR-files the entityManager will never be injected.

I'm using the @PersistenceContext annotation for injection.

I have a beans.xml in all META-INF folders and everything (excepted entityManager) is injected correctly. It doesn't even matter if I place a persistence.xml in all JAR-files or only in the WAR-file.

Does anybody have a glue how this can be done?

Where do I have to place the different configuration files (beans.xml, persistence.xml)?

Do I need an ejb-jar.xml file?

Is this possible at all?

Technology-Stack:
JBoss 6.1 / PrimeFaces 3.2 / Maven / EJB 3.1 / Hibernate / JTA / CDI

Answer (score 0):

You need a persistence.xml file in every jar that contains entities.
Every such persistence xml should define a different persistence unit.

If you want one persistence unit to refer to entities define in a different persistence unit then you need to include it as jar-file entry in the persistence unit definition (see example below).
This works for us for a very similar stack JBoss 5.1 (and then 7)/ EJB3/ Hibernate, Maven, ...

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
             version="1.0">

```
<persistence-unit name="PersistenceUnitA">
    <jar-file>JarContainingOtherPersistenceUnit</jar-file>
    <jta-data-source>java:/jboss-mysql-ds</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```